# multiple request for delete and get node

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Im using the request library to make rest calls to an API thats hosted locally (MailDev client)

I can delete , send and read emails when running the respective components separately. However when I run it all together I can only delete and send. The Get request always returns an empty response.

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var urlStr = 'http://localhost:1080/email/all'
var options = {
    url: urlStr,
    method: 'DELETE'
};


request.del('http://localhost:1080/email/all')

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 port: 1025,
 ignoreTLS: true,
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'email1@googlemail.com', // sender address
  to: 'email2@yahoo.com', // list of receivers
  subject: 'Hello world', // Subject line
  html: '<p>Hello world, stay happy :)</p>'// plain text body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
   if(err)
     console.log(err)
   else
      console.log();
});

console.log("getting emails");


request('http://localhost:1080/email/',function(err,res,body){
  if(err){console.log(err);}
  console.log(body);
});
```

Any ideas why the request for get only works in isolation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is firing all request pretty much at the same time. It is not guaranteed which request will finish first, therefore the order in which you call them does not guarantee that they will execute in the same sequence. Try using this:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var urlStr = 'http://localhost:1080/email/all'
var options = {
    url: urlStr,
    method: 'DELETE'
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 port: 1025,
 ignoreTLS: true,
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'email1@googlemail.com', // sender address
  to: 'email2@yahoo.com', // list of receivers
  subject: 'Hello world', // Subject line
  html: '<p>Hello world, stay happy :)</p>'// plain text body
};

deleteEmails(function(){
  sendMail(mailOptions, function(){
    getEmails(function(res, body){
      console.log(body);
    })
  })
})

function deleteEmails(successCallback){
  request.del('http://localhost:1080/email/all', function (err){
    if(err)
      console.log(err)
    else if(successCallback) {
      successCallback()
    }
  })
}

function sendMail(mailOptions, successCallback){
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
    if(err)
      console.log(err)
    else if(successCallback) {
      successCallback()
    }
  });
}

function getEmails(successCallback){
  console.log("getting emails");
  request('http://localhost:1080/email/',function(err,res,body){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      successCallback(res, body)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This helped me alot, I forgot js was asynchronous. Thanks